# How to add breakpoint to a javascript file using a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add a break-point to the source JavaScript file using a chrome Extension. But it says the

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.debugger.attach({"tabId" : tab.id }}, "1.0");
   chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
        "tabId": tab.id},
    "Debugger.setBreakpoint",
            {
                "Location": {"lineNumber": 12},
            },
    function(response) {
          chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
});

var version = "1.0";
```

It gives me a error saying the parameter 'Location' with type object not found .

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [says](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/debugger#command-setBreakpoint) the *parameter name* is `location`, not Location.

In javascript Capitalized identifiers denote classes commonly, while the variables/parameters use lower camelCase.

P.S. to see what actually happens it's very useful to ["sniff" the debugger protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#sniffing-the%20protocol) while doing the action manually in devtools.